# Share cookbook is failing with error Could not find user

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to share the chef cookbook to the supermarket which is failing with the below error. I am using the below command to share it

```
knife supermarket share starter Utilities
```

```
TRACE: Temp cookbook directory is "/var/folders/9p/rjpmy7w92ws4ctk0hdt0qwwm0000gq/T/chef-starter-build20231102-50411-xogs12"
Making tarball starter.tgz
DEBUG: Signing: method: post, url: https://supermarket.chef.io/api/v1/cookbooks, file: #<File:0x00007f8c5e2b55b0>, User-id: ykurmi, Timestamp: 2023-11-02T07:13:05Z
ERROR: Could not find user 'ykurmi'.
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create or log in using the chef infra (https://api.chef.io/) account to the chef supermarket(https://supermarket.chef.io/) account.

In my case, I just have an infra account with **ykurmi** user and was trying to share the cookbook to supermarket. Later I logged in to supermarket using the chef infra user and it worked.